# Routing with socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm writing an express app.js with socket.io, and came across a problem.
I can't figure out how to use the routes.
I want the client to write for example `localhost:3000/?id=3` and get something according to the id.
But in the socket.io connection event I dont know the url or the params (or is there a way?)

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {/*should be something according to the id in the url*/});
```

untill now I just checked the id with

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    //req.query.id
});
```

Anyone knows a way around this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you may be a bit confused about how you use webSockets.  If you want to make an http request such as `localhost:3000/?id=3`, then you don't use webSockets.  You use the normal routing mechanisms in Express.

A webSocket connection is created and then persists.  From then on, you define messages with optional data as arguments for those messages and you can send these messages either direction on the webSocket.  webSocket messages are sent on an existing webSocket, not to a URL.  You could create a message for sending URLs from client to server if you wanted.  If that was the case, you could do this in the client:

```
socket.emit("sendURL", url);
```

And, then you would listen for the `"sendURL"` message on the server.